# What is the menaing of print t(); in following code?

Tags: 7, theming

I was referring the `html.tpl.php` to learn the theming guide for drupal 7, and found following code line in `html.tpl.php`,

```
<a href="<?php print $skip_link_target; ?>" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
```

Can anybody let me know what is the `print t()` in `<?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?>`. 
Is it translation function or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's Drupal's string translation function.

[`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7)

> Translates a string to the current language or to a given language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is translation function https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7 .